# Is the Thread class in Java static?

Tags: java, oop

I am currently learning Java. As soon as I got to the point where Threads were included in the lessons I wondered why Thread.sleep() can be called in the main method.

**Idea**: The Thread class is static, that is why it doesn`t need to be instantiated. *But* I wonder why I can create an object of it. How can I understand that?

**Short code snippet**:

```
class MyClass{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Thread trd  = new Thread(new MyThread());
        trd.start();

        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
       catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured");
        }
    }
}

public class SuperClass{
    int x = 5;
}

public class MyThread extends SuperClass implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        while(x<10){
            System.out.println("Hello" + x);
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the `sleep` method inside the `Thread` class is static. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen So the Thread class is not static only the `sleep()` method? and that is why I can access it via `Thread.sleep();`?

Comment: @Alan `static` classes don't even exist in java

Comment: @Lino in nested classes they can be static

Comment: @Alan that's another kind of static. It just means that an instance can be created without the instance of the enclosing class. Doesn't make the inner class `static` like in C#

Comment: @Lino I got it thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Thread` class itself isn't static, as you can see in the Java docs for [java.lang.Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> `public class Thread extends Object implements Runnable`

When a call like `Thread.sleep` is possible (so without creating an instance of a `Thread` object), it means the method `sleep` is static in this case:

> `public static void sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException`

---

Here a simply example class to illustrate how the `static` vs non-static methods work a bit more:

```
public class TestObj{
  public static void staticPrint(){
    System.out.println("Static method call");
  }

  public void regularPrint(){
    System.out.println("Non-static method call");
  }
}
```

We now can have a call like this:

```
TestObj.staticPrint();
```

But when we try the following it will give a compiler error (*non-static method regularPrint() cannot be referenced from a static context*):

```
TestObj.regularPrint();
```

Instead, you should create an instance in order to call the `regularPrint` method:

```
TestObj testObjInstance = new TestObj();
testObjInstance.regularPrint();
```

Note that it is still possible to call static methods with the instance, although it will give a warning (*The static method staticPrint() from the type TestObj should be accessed in a static way*):

```
testObjInstance.staticPrint();
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZA/b4MwEMV3PsVTJiIlZE/UqVOH/pHoFnU4wKImxkY@A4qqfnZqwKiibdTpLN@737t3FXW0N43QVXEZhlwRM14Fu@es@oiAps2UzMGOnC@dkUV4v1ipXbwdNUB6ZSfqxLQuacZ/peNNOo/Uwr2bAjkptdmevPoz@sZOPCvKVpH9F/hk9J5vQj12Xv6RpL6xee1bceo8sDy/gWzJwS4ETlbRTtHUOxxwb@pGKmEhrDV2BzYoJFOmRHEMmoWwDhMQoQk31wftfXQucAct@qUbT0HwU/SLuOzks/scIKxvYjRIQy4WktEYZul33SFrHXqpFErZCT/Zk9WecfzTd32LUTHfeRi@AA)

Comment: Oh, I get it thanks a ton! :)

Comment: @Alan Glad I could help. I made an edit with an example class to illustrate how static vs non-static method works as additional clarification. If anything is unclear feel free to ask.

Comment: I understood all thanks a ton for this awesome answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

The top level class can't be static only inner can .

your question is about why sleep method defined in class **java.lang.Thread** is static .

answer : u can call it anywhere in your code without have a reference to your thread.

sleep Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (current = thread where it's called)